# Find words next to each other in a string

Tags: c#

I need to be able to find a different number of word combinations, where the words are next to each other in a string.

Example:

the string: `one two three four`

I need to find combinations like this:

```
one two
two three
three four
one two three
two three four
```

The combinations could get large, depending on the amount of words in the string.
I'm struggling because the initial string can be any number of words long.

**EDIT**

This code isnt even close, but I'm struggling with the logic of it all. My code below makes assumptions that I wont know.

```
string[] inputs = input.Replace("/", "").Split('-');
            List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= inputs.Length; i++ )
            {
                returnList.Add(inputs[i]);
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    returnList.Add(inputs[i - 1] + " " + inputs[i] + " " + inputs[i + 1]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you paste the code you tried? It is look like an algorithm question.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to check if a specific set of words do in fact appear next to each other in the string (which is a simple check) or are you trying to build an array of strings containing every possible combination of adjacent words from the source string?

Comment: I want your second suggestion. ' build an array of strings containing every possible combination of adjacent words from the source string'

Comment: search on here for permutations, you'll find loads of stuff

Comment: permutations seems to be in the right direction, only I dont want all possible combinations from left to right, just those where the elements are next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a C# solution that uses a bit of LINQ...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string startingString = "one two three four";
        List<string> l = startingString.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        var combinations = l.Select(q => FindPairs(q, l))
                   .ToList()
                   .SelectMany(r => r);
        foreach (var combination in combinations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", combination));
        }
    }
    private static List<List<string>> FindPairs(string s, List<string> list)
    {
        List<List<string> > result = new List<List<string>>();
        int index = list.IndexOf(s);
        for (int t = 2; t < list.Count; t++)
        {
            if (index + t <= list.Count)
            {
                var words = list.Skip(index).Take(t).ToList();
                if (words.Count() >= 2)
                {
                    result.Add(words);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It produces the result...

```
one,two
one,two,three
two,three
two,three,four
three,four
```

which matches the result in your question.  The key to the solution is combining the Take and Skip operators.  LINQ's SelectMany flattens out the list of lists into a single list.

Answer (score -1):

You could start by calling a String.Split function on the source string, using " " (or other whitespace) as the separator. This will get you a string array where each element is one word. After that, used nested loops to build each string, as in the following code:

`private static List<string> GetStringCombos(string sourceString)
        {
            string[] sourceArray = sourceString.Split(' ');
            var newStrings = new List<string>();
            for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < sourceArray.Length; startIndex++)
            {
                for (int endIndex = startIndex; endIndex < sourceArray.Length; endIndex++)
                {
                    string newString = "";
                    for (int currentIndex = startIndex; currentIndex <= endIndex; currentIndex++)
                    {
                        newString = string.Join(" ", newString, sourceArray[currentIndex]);
                    }
                    newStrings.Add(newString.Trim());
                }
            }
            return newStrings;
        }`

Comment: You should use a StringBuilder in the nested loops if you expect large combinations (i.e. a long input string)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.